# Make the background through javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, background

I want to put the background after you download the entire code and files in html. It can however be done. Make it so that the background is loaded after all the content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set it after the DOM loads:

```
$(function() {
    $("body").css("background-color", "red");
});
```

or after the whole page (e.g. images) has loaded:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $("body").css("background-color", "red");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If by background you mean a background image:

```
$(function(){
    $('body').css('background','url(\'url-to-background-image\')');
});
```